# Modifying CPU Paramteres in Gem5 From Config

Tags: cpu-architecture, gem5

Many CPU parameters in the O3 CPU are initialised by reading out of a 'params' object passed to their the class of the different components (fetch, decode etc). For instance:

```cpp
Fetch::Fetch(CPU *_cpu, const BaseO3CPUParams &params)
    : fetchPolicy(params.smtFetchPolicy),
      cpu(_cpu),
      branchPred(nullptr),
      decodeToFetchDelay(params.decodeToFetchDelay),
    ...
{
```

I want to add a new parameter that can be modified via the command line with the config script (in my case `configs/example/se.py`). I've implemented this by adding a new option in `/configs/common/Options.py` and the following code in `se.py`:

```py
for cpu in system.cpu:
    cpu.my_new_param = args.my_new_param
```

I've then added the new parameter field to `BaseCPU.py` as: `my_new_param = Param.String(...)`

The problem is that I'm restoring from checkpoints into the atomic CPU, then switching to the O3 CPU where I want my new parameter to be used.  It seems in this case, the CPUs in `system.cpu` (which is a list) is only ever the atomic CPU object.

How can I access the `DerivO3CPU` object from the `se.py` script then? What's the best way to set this parameter at the command line so I don't have to rebuild every time I want to change it?

Thanks.